# Matplotlib trying to draw a circle though basic equation ( x**2 + y**2 = 9)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some mathematical equations. Using code below gave almost lilke an ellipse instead of a circle. Is there a way to improve the shape ..i tried increasing steps.  Not sure if another module would be better or really needed ? Also can i just give the equation as an input somehow ..so i dont have to use np.sqrt. I went through some of already answered questions but either they are too specific or too complex. So kindly dont mark it a duplicate. Just looking for a genric solution here as I would need to plot parabola and hyperbola as well.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
x = np.arange(0, 1000 , 0.001)
y = np.sqrt(9 - np.power(x,2))

# Plot the points using matplotlib
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

=======================================================
Using some suggestions, Tried to plot y and -y as well.. but circle doesn't complete on left side.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)
y = np.sqrt(9 - np.power(x, 2))

# Plot the points using matplotlib
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, -y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You *cannot* plot a circle by defining `y` as a function of `x`: you could at best get a semicircle, as such a function cannot produce the necessary two values of `y` for most valid values of `x`.  What you want is a *parametric equation*, with both coordinates separately defined as functions of some parameter.  The equation you started with doesn't really work in such terms, the usual way to make a parametric circle would be to use `x=sin(p)` and `y=cos(p)`, where `p` is an angle that ranges over a full circle.

Comment: `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')` will set the aspect ratio between the axes equal, to so circles will appear round instead of oval.

Comment: @jasonharper - yes you are right.. i tried sin/cos method too but it was a bit jaggedy. but thanks for showing another way.

Comment: Also tried plotting y and -y in my code but funny the final shape or circle doesnt complete one left side.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to set a linspace which contains all values you need, i saw that you tried to plot a radius 3 circle.

```
x = np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, 1000)
y = np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, 1000)
```

After that, make a meshgrid with numpy and use matplotlib to plot your contour. Notice that `F` is your circle equation.

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

F = X**2 + Y**2 - 9.0
```

Finally, just call matplotlib and plot your figure as a contour.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.contour(X,Y,F,[0])

ax.set_aspect(1)

plt.title('My Circle', fontsize=8)

plt.xlim(-10,10)
plt.ylim(-10,10)

plt.grid(linestyle='--')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes this kind of works..so thanks for this .. just curious using Can any other modules/libraries may help the smoothing of shape.. for ex: seaborn ..or ggplot or bokeh.

Comment: I suggest you to check this tutorial: [Seaborn Circle](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/58791567.shtml)